# How to install ipa file on simulator or real device?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, simulator, xcuitest

I have `ipa` file and I can extract the app file if I dragged and drop the app file to simulator it's crashing in the landing page,
Whenever I'm dragging the ipa file to device and simulator manager I'm unable to install it for both simulator and real ios

However, when I am using same `ipa` file with BrowserStack it's installing the `ipa` without any problem and its working fine.

I am not sure what I'm missing

**What is the correct follow of installing the ipa/app file for both emulator and simulator?**

Comment: An ipa is either a simulator build (x86) or a device build (arm). It isn't both.

Comment: So why i couldnt use it in real ios locally but it works on browserstack ios device

Comment: Because Browserstack provides remote access to physical devices that run ARM builds.

Comment: So still why my real ios didnt accept the same ipa, whats browserstack is providing more than what i can do. Maybe im missing something can mentioned steps how to install an ipa on real ios device

Comment: Does your ipa include the right provisioning profile that includes the uuid for your device?

Comment: How i can know that or how i can do that, also does this requires ios developer program account . Simply this ipa is a build for an app that im testing, im not sure if there is certain requirement i should ask developer to do during build the ipa so i can use it with simulator or real ios

Comment: The developer needs to provide you with an ad-hoc build for your device or (probably easier) use TestFlight  They can also provide you with a build specifically for the simulator

Comment: In case if i want run automation test using appium, how theb i will stall the ipa through appium server. There must be away to send the ipa directly so you can execute you automation script

Comment: **There is a good answer here** [Solution to install an .IPA on a Simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72015509/how-to-install-ipa-in-ios-simulator/76917760#76917760)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To install the app on iOS Simulator:

```
xcrun simctl install <Simulator ID> <Path to .ipa>
```

Comment: I got this error: 
xcrun simctl install 19204C17-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-74A0A8185D6E /Users/xxxxx/Downloads/xxxxx.ipa
An error was encountered processing the command (domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code=2):
Failed to install the requested application
An application bundle was not found at the provided path.
Provide a valid path to the desired application bundle.

Comment: Are you sure that you get .ipa file build specially  for Simulator? Please note, it's not possible to install on Simulator .ipa files for devices.

Comment: **There is a good answer here** 

[Solution to install an .IPA on a Simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72015509/how-to-install-ipa-in-ios-simulator/76917760#76917760)

Comment: It should be `xcrun simctl install <Simulator ID> <Path to .app>`. IPA is not for Simulator.