# How to install IPA in ios simulator?

Tags: ios, xcode, ipa

I build one `.ipa` after using `Xcode` archive then distribute as `ad hoc`
Normally I copy this to a real ios device but today it is failing, says "failed to install"

The problem is that using xcode -> window -> Devices and simulators
does not show me the running simulator.

I have one running ios simulator but i cannot see it there so don't know how to copy my ipa into it

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install ipa file on simulator or real device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60458488/how-to-install-ipa-file-on-simulator-or-real-device)

Answer (score 1):

It is my understanding that .ipa's are only meant for physical devices. For the simulator I think you need to use the .app file. You might have to unzip something first.

Answer (score -5):

Currently, this is easy to achieve.

Steps

1. Go to google and type

> apple app apple-configurator-2

2. Then install the app [Link to Apple Configurator](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/apple-configurator/id1037126344?mt=12)
3. Connect your Apple Mobile Device to your Mac Desktop via USB or iCloud ***(I did it using a cable)***
4. Click on the Device that you wish to install your IPA file
   [image]
5. Click **Add** and select **Apps** from the drop-down
   [image]
6. Select **Choose from my Mac**
   [image]
7. Find the **IPA file** on your desktop, select it, then click **Add**
8. Configurator will display a loading bar, the IPA File will be ready for use on your device once the bar is loaded.
   [image]
9. Enjoy the app

Comment: Your answer is for real device, not Simulator.

Comment: Now apple have arm64 simulator. Why it doesn't work?